# IPhone - Full screen UIScrollView starts right but repositions itself below navigation bar

Tags: iphone, fullscreen, offset, scrollview, navigationbar

I am currently trying to implement a photo picker just like the Photo App but with a custom image source.
For the "photo scrolling" part I used the Apple PhotoScroller sample code and adapted it. One of the main difference is that it is now embedded in a navigation controller (wich is the photoPicker own nav controller, not the application's one) , with a navigation bar.
I have the status and navigation bar translucent and I did set wantsFullScreenLayout = YES on all the view controller used in the photoPicker. It seems to work nearly fine. The "Overview" view (the one which displays thumbnails of all the album's photos) is indeed fullscreen, and I have to offset it manually so the thumbnails are displayed under the navigation bar at first.
For the scrolling part however there is a glitch.
For those who don't know the photoScroller sample code, it works with a custom UIViewController (PhotoViewController) with a UIScrollView attribute (pagingScrollView), and a set of custom UIScrollView (ImageScrollView) with a UIView and an NSInteger index attributes. The ImageScrollView instances are then added/removed as subviews of the PhotoScroller.

Below is some related code :

PhotoViewController.h

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *pagingScrollView;

    NSMutableSet *recycledPages;
    NSMutableSet *visiblePages;

    IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *previousButtonItem;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *nextButtonItem;

    id<PhotoViewDataSource> dataSource;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *pagingScrollView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *recylcledPages;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *visiblePages;

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *previousButtonItem;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *nextButtonItem;

@property(nonatomic, retain) id<PhotoViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

PhotoViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Configure the scrollView
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
    pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
    pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * [self.dataSource imageCount],
                                              pagingScrollViewFrame.size.height);
    //pagingScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.view = pagingScrollView;

    // TODO ? Prepare to tile content
    recycledPages = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    visiblePages  = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [self processPages];
}


- (void)processPages {

    // Calculate which pages are visible
    CGRect visibleBounds = pagingScrollView.bounds;
    NSLog(@"PhotoViewController - processPages : frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.frame));
    NSLog(@"pagingScrollView bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.bounds));
    NSLog(@"and contentSize = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(pagingScrollView.contentSize));

    int firstNeededPageIndex = floorf(CGRectGetMinX(visibleBounds) / CGRectGetWidth(visibleBounds));
    int lastNeededPageIndex  = floorf((CGRectGetMaxX(visibleBounds)-1) / CGRectGetWidth(visibleBounds));
    firstNeededPageIndex = MAX(firstNeededPageIndex, 0);
    lastNeededPageIndex  = MIN(lastNeededPageIndex, [dataSource imageCount] - 1);

    if (lastNeededPageIndex >= 0) {

        // Recycle no-longer-visible pages 
        for (ImageScrollView *page in visiblePages) {
            if (page.index < firstNeededPageIndex || page.index > lastNeededPageIndex) {
                [recycledPages addObject:page];
                [page removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        [visiblePages minusSet:recycledPages];

        // add missing pages
        for (int index = firstNeededPageIndex; index <= lastNeededPageIndex; index++) {
            if (![self isDisplayingPageForIndex:index]) {
                ImageScrollView *page = [self dequeueRecycledPage];
                if (page == nil) {
                    page = [[[ImageScrollView alloc] init] autorelease];
                }
                [self configurePage:page forIndex:index];
                NSLog(@"PhotoViewController - processPage 2 : bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.bounds));
                [pagingScrollView addSubview:page];
                NSLog(@"PhotoViewController - processPage 3 : bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.bounds));
                [visiblePages addObject:page];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (ImageScrollView *)dequeueRecycledPage {
    ImageScrollView *page = [recycledPages anyObject];
    if (page) {
        [[page retain] autorelease];
        [recycledPages removeObject:page];
    }
    return page;
}

- (BOOL)isDisplayingPageForIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    BOOL foundPage = NO;
    for (ImageScrollView *page in visiblePages) {
        if (page.index == index) {
            foundPage = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundPage;
}

- (void)configurePage:(ImageScrollView *)page forIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    page.index = index;
    page.frame = [self frameForPageAtIndex:index];

    NSLog(@"PhotoViewController - configurePage : bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.bounds));

    [page displayImage:[dataSource imageForImageId:index]];

    NSLog(@"PhotoViewController - configurePage 2 : bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(pagingScrollView.bounds));
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ScrollView delegate methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self processPages];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark  Frame calculations
#define PADDING  10

- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView {
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    frame.origin.x -= PADDING;
    frame.size.width += (2*PADDING);
    return frame;
}

- (CGRect)frameForPageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];

    CGRect pageFrame = pagingScrollViewFrame;
    pageFrame.size.width -= (2 * PADDING);
    pageFrame.origin.x = (pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * index) + PADDING;
    //pageFrame.origin.x = (pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * index) - (PADDING*index*2);
    return pageFrame;
}
```

ImageScrollView.h

```
@interface ImageScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIView        *imageView;
    NSUInteger     index;
}
@property (assign) NSUInteger index;

- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image;
//- (void)displayTiledImageNamed:(NSString *)imageName size:(CGSize)imageSize;
- (void)configureForImageSize:(CGSize)imageSize;
```

ImageScrollView.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen

    CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = imageView.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    else
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

    imageView.frame = frameToCenter;
    NSLog(@"imageView frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(frameToCenter));

    if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[TilingView class]]) {
        // to handle the interaction between CATiledLayer and high resolution screens, we need to manually set the
        // tiling view's contentScaleFactor to 1.0. (If we omitted this, it would be 2.0 on high resolution screens,
        // which would cause the CATiledLayer to ask us for tiles of the wrong scales.)
        imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollView delegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Configure scrollView to display new image (tiled or not)

- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // clear the previous imageView
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [imageView release];
    imageView = nil;

    // reset our zoomScale to 1.0 before doing any further calculations
    self.zoomScale = 1.0;

    // make a new UIImageView for the new image
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    [self configureForImageSize:[image size]];
}

- (void)configureForImageSize:(CGSize)imageSize 
{
    CGSize boundsSize = [self bounds].size;

    // set up our content size and min/max zoomscale
    CGFloat xScale = boundsSize.width / imageSize.width;    // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image width-wise
    CGFloat yScale = boundsSize.height / imageSize.height;  // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image height-wise
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(xScale, yScale);                 // use minimum of these to allow the image to become fully visible

    // on high resolution screens we have double the pixel density, so we will be seeing every pixel if we limit the
    // maximum zoom scale to 0.5.
    CGFloat maxScale = /*1.0 / */[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    // don't let minScale exceed maxScale. (If the image is smaller than the screen, we don't want to force it to be zoomed.) 
    if (minScale > maxScale) {
        minScale = maxScale;
    }

    self.contentSize = imageSize;
    self.maximumZoomScale = maxScale;
    self.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    self.zoomScale = minScale;  // start out with the content fully visible
}
```

My problem is that the pagingScrollView is being offset to an origin of (0, -64) pixels (height of status bar + nav bar I suppose) when I first load the PhotoViewController instance. This results in a messed-up interface in which the ImageScrollView appears below the nav bar (origin (0, 0)) and can then be scrolled up and down even when its height is smaller than the screen.

With some logs and breakpoints I was able to determine that the pagingScrollView bounds are fine at the beginning of the loading process. They change when I scale the image of the ImageScrollView to fit the screen. This causes the viewForZoomingInScrollView and then the scrollViewDidScroll methods to be called. The pagingScrollView is being offset during those calls.

I tried setting the offset manually but when I do it in processPages the scrollView can no longer bounce up and down...

Any help will be appreciated !

Cheers

PB

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Three20 has a really nice implementation of it. If you need any fancy feature, it's only adapt the code for your own necessity.

All the hard work is already done. Although if you still want to implement your own version, at least have a look at Three20 code and check how they do what you're trying to achieve.

How it looks like: http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3432/3378117315_3bf905bdb6_o.jpg

Source code: http://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: Three20 isn't really the solution for this if you only want to accomplish that screen. It's not so customizable as if you did the view yourself, and you have to include a HUGE library just for this...

Comment: Hi @JavierSoto, That's an old reply and at that time Three20 had one of the best open source photo galleries. If you read my answer you will see that I've suggested the P.B to use it or have look at the code to see how they implemented that. I personally don't like Three20 lib.

Answer (score 6):

In your particular case (i.e. the `PhotoViewController` being pushed onto a `UINavigationController` stack) - navigation bars add a `contentInset` to `PhotoViewController`'s scroll view. This is all better explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW9) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW28).

That is, the `PhotoViewController` view does not fit tightly to your window bounds and thus, has room to be scrolled in all directions.

I found 2 possible solutions to your problem.

1 - You need to manually adjust the `contentInset` of your `pagingScrollView` to compensate for the height of the navigation bar and status bar. Add this to `PhotoViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat topOffset = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
    pagingScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-topOffset, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

**OR**

2 - Since only scroll views have a `contentInset`, wrap the `pagingScrollView` in a plain `UIView`:

```
- (void)loadView {    
    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];

    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
    photoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
    pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];

    // ... configure the pagingScrollView

    [photoView addSubview:pagingScrollView];
    self.view = photoView;

    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx, that was more or less what I was trying to do but didn't know the right way. That said, I did not test it, I switched to Three20 app, wich does just exactly was I need, and more :)

Answer (score 0):

The main things that need to be set are the following in your view controller. Use autoresize flags on your content views. Enabling the following flags will expand the size of your view controller to the full size of the screen. I perform the following in viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]; // if you want to underlap status
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; // underlap nav controller
    self.toolbar.translucent = YES; // if you have a toolbar.
}
```

more details can be found here in apple's docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2

if you have been doing things to set frame bounds on the content view I would remove all that code because the above should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Adjust Scroll View insets of view controller to false from storyboard.